# Joining int in python as a list

Tags: python

My input is looking like this right now:

`[6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9]`, `[7, 1, 5, 6, 7]`, `[1, 2, 0, 6, 3, 3, 8]`, `[8, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]`

I want to make a list looking like this:

`[675299, 71567, 1206338, 805123]`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

transforming a list of digits to an integer is as simple as:

```
l = [6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9]
n = int(''.join(map(str, l)))
```

where `n` holds your result.

adapting this to a list of lists of digits is trivial:

```
l = [ 
    [6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9],
    [7, 1, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 0, 6, 3, 3, 8],
    [8, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]
]

n = [ int(''.join(map(str, t))) for t in l ]
```

again, `n` holds your result:

```
>>> print(n)
[675299, 71567, 1206338, 805123]
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for your suggestion - it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

This is variant without string conversions:

```
>>> [sum([10**k*j for k,j in enumerate(i)]) for i in l]
[675299, 71567, 1206338, 805123]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrays = [6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9], [7, 1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 0, 6, 3, 3, 8], [8, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]
str_arrays = [[str(number) for number in array] for array in arrays]
[int(''.join(array)) for array in str_arrays]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.join()` method only works with strings... so when you try to use it with integers, it doesn't work!

You can achieve what you want using the following code:

```
lst = [[6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9],[7, 1, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 0, 6, 3, 3, 8],[8, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]]

new_lst = []

# i'm going to iter over the list to join the items inside of it
# then i'll create a new number by joining each item inside each input list 
# and then append it to a new list
for item in lst:
    new_number = ''.join(str(x) for x in item)
    new_number = int(new_number)
    new_lst.append(new_number)

print new_lst
```

Output: `[675299, 71567, 1206338, 805123]`

If you want to study this topic, search: `join list integers python`

Comment: he wanted list of integers not strings

Answer (score 0):

If you're drunk you'll find this as straightforward

```
>>> l = [6, 7, 5, 2, 9, 9], [7, 1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 0, 6, 3, 3, 8], [8, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l = eval (str(l).replace(", ","").replace("][",","))
>>> l
[675299, 71567, 1206338, 805123]
```

Comment: for the record: this takes about 2.5x as long as the non-eval solutions.