# Converting list values into a string facing an error in python using .join()

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to convert the elements of a list into a single string, but it somehow does not work; here's my code:

```
def dec_to_bin(num):
    bin_num = []

    while num > 1:
        bin_num.append(num % 2)
        num = num // 2

    if num == 1:
        bin_num.append(1)

    return(bin_num[::-1])

sample = dec_to_bin(19)
converted = " "
print(converted.join(sample))
```

When I run the program, I'm shown this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Any help around this issue is appreciated.

Comment: `converted.join([str(e) for e in sample])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining int in python as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222288/joining-int-in-python-as-a-list)

Comment: @crissal surprisingly your solution works, but I don't understand how mine won't... What's the difference?

Comment: Because the elements of `sample` are integers.  You can't `join` a list of integers into a string, you have to convert the integers to strings first.

Comment: @Mania why surprisingly? You need to know what you're doing. `sample` is a list of integers, and as @Tim Roberts said, you need first to convert integers to string - `[str(e) for e in sample]` - and then you can join this list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def dec_to_bin(num):
    bin_num = []

    while num > 1:
        bin_num.append(num % 2)
        num = num // 2

    if num == 1:
        bin_num.append(1)

    return(bin_num[::-1])

sample = dec_to_bin(19)
ans = ("".join(str(x) for x in sample))
print(ans)
```